# User inputs command to list - list index out of range when command[1] not present

Tags: python, scripting

So I have a CLI written in python that I use to automate tasks. I run the CLI out of a command prompt window. The CLI accepts user input, once you issue a command and hit enter the cli will run through a series of "if" statements and if the command matches it runs that task. If there is no match it passes it to command prompt. There are cases when I want to issue command[0] without command[1]... but since I specify command[1] it will throw "list index out of range". Is there a way around this?..

```
def shell(status1):
    while status1 == 0:
        shell = (socket.gethostname())
        cmd = input("%s#"%(shell))
        cmd = cmd.split()
        for i in cmd:
            if cmd[0] == "ssh":
                ip = cmd[1]
                os.system("putty -ssh -l %s -pw %s %s -2"%(username, password, ip))     
        cmd = ' '.join(cmd)
        os.system("%s"%(cmd))
    exit()
home(0)
```

Comment: Maybe try using a `try`/`except` block to catch said error

Comment: Maybe try checking the length of the list, first.

Comment: Wow this seems like such an easy answer... worked for me! Thanks!